# Turning on/off Mojave's Screenshot Preview Thumbnails via Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, macos-mojave

How do I `show`/`hide` macOS Mojave Screenshot Preview Floating Thumbnails via Terminal commands?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to turn off the feature execute:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture show-thumbnail -bool FALSE
```

To turn it back on

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture show-thumbnail -bool TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

For the changes to take effect after typing command `show-thumbnail -bool FALSE`, user should restart the `SystemUIServer` service using bash command `killall`:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture show-thumbnail -bool FALSE

killall SystemUIServer
```

Hope this helps.